# How to know when to Commit or Rollback a Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm trying to learn how and when to commit /rollback transactions. 
I'm using an `IF` condition to test whether the code produces errors and if it does, I want to Rollback.

What is the best way to test your code so that you will know when to Commit or Rollback.

Ive tried the code below but im getting this error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>   Incorrect syntax near '*'.

```
Begin Transaction DBChallenge1Setup
 Create Table EmployeeRecords(
                            EmployeeID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY
                            PpsNo varchar(8),
                            FirstName varchar(50),
                            LastName varchar(50),
                            Department varchar(50),
                            SupervisorId varchar(50),
                            PhoneNo varchar(50),
                            EmailAddress varchar(50),
                            DateOfBirth date);
Insert Into EmployeeRecords
                    Values(1, '5686213Q', 'Dan', 'Roche', 'IT',232, '012323232', 'danroche@itsolutions.com', '1970-04-10'),
                            (2, '6534223Q', 'Nicholas', 'Martin', 'IT',233, '012323233', 'nicholasmartin@itsolutions.com', '1974-12-01'),
                            (232, '9514223W', 'Jane', 'Donnelly', 'IT',999, '012323234', 'janedonnelly@itsolutions.com', '1960-02-12'),
                            (233, '4212223S', 'Amy', 'Smythe', 'IT',999, '012323235', 'amysmythe@itsolutions.com', '1967-09-11');

Select * From EmployeeRecords
Select @@Rowcount As RecordsEntered, @@ERROR As Errors
if @@Error > 0 ROLLBACK Transaction DBChallenge1Setup
if @@Error = 0 Commit Transaction DBChallenge1Setup;
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Also, the `*` is giving you an error. Remove it. and you have no `,` between columns in your create statement.

Comment: How about using a `Try Catch` block.

Comment: Im using SSMS. Ive added the commas. I need the * as I want to return all columns. Im not familiar with Try Catch.but will look it up. Im trying to use Commit/Rollback correctly first.

Comment: The `*` next to the `PRIMARY KEY` in the `CREATE` statement is what I was talking about removing.

Comment: sorry. i ver seen that. I copied the dummy data from a word doc.

Comment: The edited  code above  is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `try/catch` to handle unexpected errors;

```
begin try
Begin Transaction DBChallenge1Setup
 Create Table EmployeeRecords(
                            EmployeeID varchar(50,) PRIMARY KEY
                            PpsNo varchar(8),
                            FirstName varchar(50),
                            LastName varchar(50),
                            Department varchar(50),
                            SupervisorId varchar(50),
                            PhoneNo varchar(50),
                            EmailAddress varchar(50),
                            DateOfBirth date)
Insert Into EmployeeRecords
                    Values(1, '5686213Q', 'Dan', 'Roche', 'IT',232, '012323232', 'danroche@itsolutions.com', '1970-04-10'),
                            (2, '6534223Q', 'Nicholas', 'Martin', 'IT',233, '012323233', 'nicholasmartin@itsolutions.com', '1974-12-01'),
                            (232, '9514223W', 'Jane', 'Donnelly', 'IT',999, '012323234', 'janedonnelly@itsolutions.com', '1960-02-12'),
                            (233, '4212223S', 'Amy', 'Smythe', 'IT',999, '012323235', 'amysmythe@itsolutions.com', '1967-09-11');
Commit Transaction DBChallenge1Setup;
end try
begin catch
   ROLLBACK Transaction DBChallenge1Setup
end catch
```

You should rollback the transaction within catch block. Also, it could be better to log occured error details within catch block using `ERROR_MESSAGE()`  `ERROR_SEVERITY()` etc.

Comment: How do you know the tran is successful before using the commit

Comment: The `TRY` will control whether it will `commit` or go to the `Catch`. `TRY` means try it, if it doesn't work then go to the `Catch`

Comment: my point is the try might work but might not work correctly. how do you know the data entered is correct before commiting

Comment: "the data entered is correct " what do you mean ? Do you want to check your specific logic from SQL Server ?

Comment: Assume I run an update within a try. the update might work but how do i know it worked correctly. should a check constraint be included to verify the update before committing

Comment: If sql server get any trouble with constraint, it throws an error and you can catch it within catch block.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Is Try Catch the recommended way to use Commit/Rollback now. Im using Sql Server 2017

Comment: Yes, it is clear way to handle errors. Also, if you want to determine logical unwanted issues, you can provide required controls and you can perform rollback according to circumstance.

Comment: Where would i use the Select * From Employee Records and where would I use @@Rowcount in the above code

Comment: @@ROWCOUNT gets number of rows affected. For example, if you want to get deleted row count after delete script you can use @@ROWCOUNT.